# How to add the GCP (Google Cloud Storage) storage properties in application.yml in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am currently trying to set up an GCP storage bucket with my Spring Boot webapp for adding/removing csv and jmx files.

**The guide I am using the following properties in application.yml :**

```
gcpProperties:
  gcs:
    bucket:
      name: dpaas-assets
      scripts: gs://assets/jmeter-scripts/
      resources: gs://assets/resources/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check their [Spring Cloud GCP Storage Starter Example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-storage-resource-sample) as a Starting Guide.
If it doesn't help, providing more info would help us to help you!

eg: the error you are getting, a sample of your project, stack trace, etc